# SQL WHERE table1.column_char = table2.column_char

Tags: sql, string, where-clause

I need help with syntax for following;

```
table1.column(first 3 characters) = table2.column(first 3 characters)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [**Left** function:](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx)

```
SELECT LEFT(Name, 5) 
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductID;
GO
```

In your terms:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE LEFT(Table1.Col1,3) = LEFT(Table1.Col2,3)
```

(OR)

Use the [**Substring** function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) (*as suggested by COBRA_Fast*):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE SUBSTR(colum1, 0, 3) = SUBSTR(colum2, 0, 3)
```

Comment: Alternatively, `SUBSTR(colum, 0, 3)`, but name and support seems to vary between DBMS's.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need is regular expressions. You can do , in Oracle - REGEXP_SUBSTR  :

```
select regexp_substr('houseMate', 5) 
from dual;
```

But pleaes specify your specific database flavor.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1
(
columnA varchar(50) NULL
) 


CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2
(
columnB varchar(50) NULL
) 
GO

INSERT INTO Table1 (columnA)
 VALUES
('redDog'),
('blueCat')
GO

INSERT INTO Table2 (columnB)   
SELECT LEFT(t1.columnA, 3)          
FROM Table1 t1
GO
```

Result is 'red' and 'blu' in columnB

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE 
  SUBSTR(column1, 1, 3) = SUBSTR(column2, 1, 3);

(column1, 0, 3) would return only two characters.